File Upload Issue Axios JS
I cannot find the issue why the file payload goes empty when submitted:

Here's the network payload:

UpdateProfileInfo( payload ) {

    const formData = new FormData();
    for ( const key in payload ) {
        formData.append( key, payload[key] );
    }

    return new Promise( async ( resolve, reject ) => {
        await axios.get( '../sanctum/csrf-cookie' );
        await axios.post('/update-user', formData, {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }).then( ( res) => {
            resolve( res.data );
        }).catch( ( error ) => {
            reject({ 'message': error.message, ...error.validation });
        });
    });
}


"Here's the network payload:" - and what's the actual Content-Type header value of that request?

Ohhh, I see what you mean now, I have fixed it now :) thank you for reminding me that. LOL
